# Allow Angular directive to execute on single element at a time

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a directive to close a modal on pressing `Esc` button. But, when I have 2 overlaying modals, and I press `Esc`. My both modals are getting closed. Ideally, only topmost (say Confirmation modal) modal should have been closed. Is it possible to execute directive on a single element at a time.

Below is the code snippet of directive:

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appModal]',
})
export class ModalOperationsDirective {
  @Input() appModal;
  count: number = 0;

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event']) handleKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.appModal.close();
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-modal library for modals.

Comment: Create a service, that will hold the number of modals. Your directive will have access to this service, and on click on the Esc key, will close the last opened modal. Apart from that, it's usually a bad idea to stack up the modals, maybe you should tackle this issue instead.

Comment: There is a need to have a confirmation modal on one of the main modal for deletion. Will you please provide a code snippet for the service?

Comment: Then close the first modal and open the second one. On it for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a service that will be your source of truth :

```
export class ModalService {
  modals = [];

  openModal() {
   // Code to open a modal, then
   this.modals.push(modalRef);
  }

  closeLastModal() {
    const lastModal = this.modals.pop();
    lastModal.close();
  }
}
```

Your directive would then look like

```
export class ModalDirective {
  constructor(private service: ModalService) {

  }

  @HostListener('window:keypress.escape', [$event])
  closeModal(event) {
    this.service.closeLastModal();
  }
}
```